# django manage.py sql doesn't show index create statements

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following model:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    deviceId = models.CharField(max_length=32, db_index=True)
    transactionTime = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        index_together = [
    ["deviceId", "transactionTime"],
    ]
```

When I issue the sql command on the app: `python manage.py sql device`

I get only the table create statement and no index create statements.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use "sqlall":

```
python manage.py sqlall device
```